# Search and delete ten old files in specific folder based on file name?

Tags: c#, file, filenames, delete-file

I'm an administrator for NoName!! Company that has a router. The router creates  log files (with at least 500 MB of size for each log) and sends them to our FTP server.

The log file name is like this: ***NoName-[2014-4-4]-03-1.log***. You can see the date of create of log file in FTP server.

So I will to write a program to delete ten old log files from specific folder in FTP server which have ***LSD-RMZ*** name.

And this program must run in FTP server.

How can I search and find and delete Ten old file from ***LSD-RMZ*** Folder in C#?

Comment: __[2014-4-4]__ really? or __[2014-04-04]__??

Comment: If all you need to do is to delete 10 files, why do it in C# ? You can do it in PowerShell.. Let me know if you want this approach. If not, Aniruddha has the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory.GetFiles(path)
         .Where(x=>Regex.IsMatch(x,@"\w+\[\d+-\d+-\d+\]-\d+-\d+\.log"))
         .OrderBy(x=>DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(x,@"(?<=\[).*?(?=\])").Value))
         .Take(10)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(x=>File.Delete(x));
```

Comment: LINQ has simply made C# beautiful.